# Google App Engine: How to uniquely identify JVMs instances / measure parallelism?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jvm

In a project heavily using Tasks, I would like to record the
parallelism "from within".

On the console, I see that GAE is automatically launching new
instances of JVMs (up to 10-12) when hundreds / thousands of tasks are
enqueued. Then, they run fine.

But, I would like to record which task did run on which instance for
traçability and measurement of parallelism.

Is there any GAE or System property that I could get to uniquely
identify the JVM on which a given task is running ?

regards
didier

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no built in way to do this. What you can do, however, is to have a static variable that's initialized to something unique - such as a UUID. Thus, you can tell if two requests were handled by the same runtime if they have the same static UUID.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for this idea that I will try. Additional question: GAE duplicates elements from the 1st JVM when it starts the second and so on. Will this static uuid not be replicated as well when the class is reloaded / duplicated in the new machine? thanks didier

Comment: @Didier No, it doesn't do that - each JVM is started up fresh and loads your classfiles independently.

Comment: Nick, thanks very much, I'll experiment it live and post back results here

Answer (score 1):

[This app](http://thrdcntr.appspot.com/) might help you get started - the author wanted to experiment with tracking new instances, and includes source code.

> AppEngine automatically starts and stops JVM and threads. This application is designed to collect some data about how and when this happens.
>   It creates UUID and page access counters and stores them in various scopes:

```
* in the Memcache
* as a static field (in JVM memory)
* as a ThreadLocal
```